# How to get absolute xpath by passing the xElement name in XmlDocument or XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file nodes structure like this

```
<Employee>
    <EmpId></EmpId>
    <EmpName></EmpName>
    <Salary>
        <Basic></Basic>
        <HRA></HRA>
    </Salary>
    <Qualifications>
        <Course>
            <Name></Name>
            <Year></year>
        </course>
        <Course>
            <Name></Name>
            <Year></year>
        </course>
        <Course>
            <Name></Name>
            <Year></year>
        </course>
    </Qualifications>
<Employee>
```

From this file i want to get an absoulte xpath of any given element name(Not XElement) using XmlDocument or XDocument.
How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple XML without namespaces try this:

```
public static string GetPath(XElement element)
{
    return string.Join("/", element.AncestorsAndSelf().Reverse()
        .Select(e =>
            {
                var index = GetIndex(e);

                if (index == 1)
                {
                    return e.Name.LocalName;
                }

                return string.Format("{0}[{1}]", e.Name.LocalName, GetIndex(e));
            }));

}

private static int GetIndex(XElement element)
{
    var i = 1;

    if (element.Parent == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    foreach (var e in element.Parent.Elements(element.Name.LocalName))
    {
        if (e == element)
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Kirill Polishchuk thanks for ur reply.
you passed XElement type variable as parameter to the methods in above code ,it contains the value like  <Basic>30000</Basic> ,but in my case i will pass only 'Basic' as string.How get the full xpath by paasing xElement name as string?

Comment: @NareshReddy, And how determine XML element by its name? In XML document can be lots of elements with the same name.

Comment: @NareshReddy, Anyway, you can find first `XElement` by its name and pass it to method I've provided.

Comment: i have a list which contains the element names.using that list i will pass each name.if it has more than one element,it shuold return first element xpath.

Comment: @NareshReddy, You can use this code: `var element = doc.Descendants(elemnetName).First();`. Then pass `element` to provided method.

Comment: just i want to get the values of xml nodes by passing list xml element names one by one.The order of list values are not same how the xml file is structured.

Comment: thanks Kirill Polishchuk, I did using 
var element = doc.Descendants(elemnetName).First();.

Answer (score 0):

I acheived using `Descendants` method of `XDocument` class:

```
XElement xElement = xDocument.Descendants("Basic").First();
```

Passed XML element "Basic" as string here

```
public void ConvertObjectToXml(Employee employee )
{
    MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream();
    //To remove the default xml name space
    XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlNS = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    XmlNS.Add("", "");
    XmlSerializer XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(employee .GetType());
    XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream, employee , XmlNS);
    Stream.Flush();
    Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(Stream);
    //Paasing the "Basic" as string
    XElement xElement = xDocument.Descendants("Basic").First();
    string xpath = GetPath(xElement);
      //Paasing the "Course" as string
    XElement XElement1 =xDocument.Descendants("Course").First();
    string xpath1 = GetPath(XElement1);
}

public static string GetPath(XElement element)
{
    return string.Join("/", element.AncestorsAndSelf().Reverse()
        .Select(e => 
        {
            var index = GetIndex(e); 
            if (index == 1) 
            {
                return e.Name.LocalName; 
            }
            return string.Format("{0}[{1}]", e.Name.LocalName, GetIndex(e)); 
        })); 
} 

public static int GetIndex(XElement element) 
{
    var i = 1; 
    if (element.Parent == null) 
    {
        return 1; 
    }
    foreach (var e in element.Parent.Elements(element.Name.LocalName)) 
    {
        if (e == element)
        { 
            break; 
        }
        i++;
    }
    return i; 
}
```